# Generics with Java REST API

Tags: java, rest, generics, inheritance, jax-rs

I have a problem in accessing get method of a generic class in REST API project. there are no errors but it returns null. here I mention the code. The idea working fine when I implemented without REST API. Insert and GetALL methods are working fine in REST API but problem is Repo class Get method couldn't work with REST.

```
package lk.ac.jfn.vau.DeptApi.Model;

public class Department extends PrimaryID<Long>{
    private String Name;
    private String Location;
    
    public Department() {
        //super();
    }
    
    public Department(long id, String name, String location) {
        super(id);
        Name = name;
        Location = location;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return Location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        Location = location;
    }
    
    

}
```

```
package lk.ac.jfn.vau.DeptApi.Model;

public class PrimaryID<U> {
    private U Id;
    public PrimaryID() {
    }

    public PrimaryID(U id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public U getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(U id) {
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

```
package lk.ac.jfn.vau.DeptApi.Repo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import lk.ac.jfn.vau.DeptApi.Model.PrimaryID;

public class Repo<T extends PrimaryID<U>,U> {
     List<T> list= new ArrayList<T>();
    
    public List<T> getAll(){
        return list;
    }
    
    public void insert(T obj) {
        list.add(obj);
    }
    
    public T get(U id) {
        for(T obj:list) {
            //objects are there 
            System.out.println(obj);
            //but getId returns null
            if(obj.getId().equals(id)) {    
                return obj;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public void Delete(U id) {
        list.remove(get(id));
    }
    
    public void Update(U id,T obj) {
        list.set(list.indexOf(get(id)), obj);
    }
}
```

```
package lk.ac.jfn.vau.DeptApi.Repo;

import lk.ac.jfn.vau.DeptApi.Model.Department;

public class DepartmentRepo extends Repo<Department, Long> {

}
```

```
package lk.ac.jfn.vau.DeptApi;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import lk.ac.jfn.vau.DeptApi.Model.Department;
import lk.ac.jfn.vau.DeptApi.Repo.DepartmentRepo;

@Path("/dept")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class DepartmentResource {
    private static DepartmentRepo repo = new DepartmentRepo();

    @GET
    public List<Department> getDepartments() {
        return repo.getAll();
    }

    @POST
    public void addDepartment(Department department) {
        repo.insert(department);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Department getDepartment(@PathParam("id") long id) {
        return repo.get(id);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{id}")
    public void deleteDepartment(@PathParam("id") long id) {
        repo.Delete(id);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi there @S.Gopinath and welcome to SO. I believe that it would help potential answers if you elaborate a little on how and where you use the get method and where you get the null value. I can't see anything wrong with the existing code. For example: Is there a reason that the repo property is static?

Comment: Hi @mavrosxristoforos, There is no compile or runtime errors in my application. Even  I implemented this code without REST (without DepartmentResource .java) it worked fine.  in Repo class `public T get(U id) {
        for(T obj:list) {
            //objects are there 
            System.out.println(obj);
            //but getId returns null
            if(obj.getId().equals(id)) {    
                return obj;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }`

Comment: Hi @S.Gopinath, are you sure you have Departments on the repo before you tried to print them?

Comment: DepartmentRepo is static because to void multiple of copies of list

Comment: Yes I have two departments

Comment: What exactly does the obj contain? Does it have an Id as expected, but still the getId() method returns null??

Comment: for example the object contains 
 `"id":10001,
 "name":"Dept of ICT",
 "location":"Town"`
but method getID() returns null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Problem is Object to JSON conversion. when I updated the JSON library it worked fine.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```